# What is wrong with my T-SQL syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I keep getting the following error message when I try to run this statement. I'm running it inside of an OLE DB command in SSIS.

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Obviously this is an easy to read error message but I don't know why I'm getting it. I've checked the T-SQL documentation and I'm pretty sure I have parenthesis where they are needed.

```
INSERT INTO
  dbo.Table1 (
    [ID],
    [Supplier],
    [Level],
    [Status],
    [Core],
    [Location],
    [Outsourced],
    [Contact],
    [Phone],
    [Email]
  )
SELECT
  [ID],
  [Supplier],
  [Level],
  [Status],
  [Core],
  [Location],
  [Outsourced],
  [Contact],
  [Phone],
  [Email]
FROM
  dbo.Table2
WHERE
  NOT (
    [ID],
    [Supplier],
    [Level],
    [Status],
    [Core],
    [Location],
    [Outsourced],
    [Contact],
    [Phone],
    [Email] IN (
      SELECT
        [ID],
        [Supplier],
        [Level],
        [Status],
        [Core],
        [Location],
        [Outsourced],
        [Contact],
        [Phone],
        [Email]
      FROM
        dbo.table1
    )
  )
```

Comment: The `NOT` in your `WHERE` clause is not correct T-SQL. You can't validate multiple values with that syntax.

Comment: SQL Server does not support `where (a,b,c) not in (select ...)` you need to rewrite that as a NOT EXISTS co-related sub-query

Comment: @Igor: it is correct "SQL", it's just not valid for T-SQL

Comment: Geez these are a ton of helpful answers, I did not expect so many this fast. I'm going to test them out soon and will accept whatever is the fastest.

Comment: SQL Server sometimes gives you confusing error messages. This is one of these cases.

Comment: you have omitted to tell us what you are trying to do with this.

Comment: I have a source table and a destination table which I am combining into a "Staging table" for comparison.  On the staging table I am going to be performing various transformations depending on conditional statements. With this query I'm just trying to insert into the destination table if the entry is in the source but not the destination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update

Martin Smith wrote a great [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076853/what-is-wrong-with-my-t-sql-syntax/49076882#comment85160094_49076975) on M.Ali's answer - Are you sure you are doing the right thing here? If any of the values in any of the columns is different in both tables, the select statement will return it.
This means that if you have a record in table 2 that has the all the same values except one with a record in table 1, the select statement will return it and you might get either a primary key violation error of worst - duplicated rows (except that single column) in you table 1.
Taking that into consideration what you should probably do is select all the records from table 2 where the key columns does not exists in table 1 - any column that is a part of any unique constraint or index, not just the primary key.

So, assuming `ID` is the primary key, and for the sake of the demonstration you have a unique index on `Phone` and `Email`, what you need is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO
  dbo.Table1 (
    [ID],
    [Supplier],
    [Level],
    [Status],
    [Core],
    [Location],
    [Outsourced],
    [Contact],
    [Phone],
    [Email]
  )
SELECT
  [ID],
  [Supplier],
  [Level],
  [Status],
  [Core],
  [Location],
  [Outsourced],
  [Contact],
  [Phone],
  [Email]
FROM
  dbo.Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
    OR (t1.Phone = t2.Phone AND t1.Email = t2.Email)
)
```

### First version

The `IN` operator doesn't work like that in SQL Server. It can have only one operand on it's left side, and many operands on it's rights side, so it basically compares a single value to a list.
T-SQL `IN` operator works like this:

```
Col IN(value1, value2....valuen)
```

is equivalent to

```
Col = value1 or Col = value2....or Col = valuen`
```

It is valid in standard SQL and there are databases that supports it such as MySql, but SQL Server doesn't.

You are looking for [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql):

```
INSERT INTO
  dbo.Table1 (
    [ID],
    [Supplier],
    [Level],
    [Status],
    [Core],
    [Location],
    [Outsourced],
    [Contact],
    [Phone],
    [Email]
  )
SELECT
  [ID],
  [Supplier],
  [Level],
  [Status],
  [Core],
  [Location],
  [Outsourced],
  [Contact],
  [Phone],
  [Email]
FROM
  dbo.Table2
EXCEPT 
      SELECT
        [ID],
        [Supplier],
        [Level],
        [Status],
        [Core],
        [Location],
        [Outsourced],
        [Contact],
        [Phone],
        [Email]
      FROM
        dbo.table1
```

Comment: the updated answer on this one is exactly what I need (Sans unique constraints on anything except the primary key). Thank you and @Martin for your answers and everyone else who has contributed to helping me with this.

Comment: Glad to help, though without Martin's commend I would probably not think of it myself...

Comment: Well he has not posted his own answer, I've always wished stack overflow would allow some way to reward those who contribute greatly to a discussion without actually providing the official answer. Like rep gifting or something similar.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how much reputation can you or me give out to someone with 316K rep that would actually make a difference... I guess you'll have to ask some more questions and hope he answers them :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using `Exists` can give you a much faster query, sometimes even faster than a `left join where righttable.PK_Column is null` queries.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 
          ([ID],[Supplier],[Level],[Status],[Core],[Location]
            ,[Outsourced],[Contact],[Phone],[Email])
SELECT
  [ID],
  [Supplier],
  [Level],
  [Status],
  [Core],
  [Location],
  [Outsourced],
  [Contact],
  [Phone],
  [Email]
FROM
  dbo.Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                   FROM dbo.table1 t1
                    WHERE t2.[ID]        = t2.[ID]
                          t2.[Supplier]  = t2.[Supplier]
                          t2.[Level]     = t2.[Level]
                          t2.[Status]    = t2.[Status]
                          t2.[Core]      = t2.[Core]
                          t2.[Location]  = t2.[Location]
                          t2.[Outsourced]= t2.[Outsourced]
                          t2.[Contact]   = t2.[Contact]
                          t2.[Phone]     = t2.[Phone]
                          t2.[Email]     = t2.[Email] 
                  )
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see if except is slower or faster then not exists. My guess is that they will run pretty much the same speed, maybe even have the same execution plan. I have to say that IMHO, except is more suitable in this case.

Comment: tbh I'm not convinced any of the answers on this page really give the needed semantics. does the OP really want duplicate id values if the row exists but some of the column values are different?

Comment: @MartinSmith good point! however I think that both M.Ali's answer and mine will do what the OP wants to do. If that's the correct thing to do or not - well, that's a great question and I agree that it's probably the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

IN takes exactly ONE column name on the left, you can't put a list of columns on the left. I'm honestly not exactly sure what you're going for here... it doesn't make a lot of sense.  But you probably want something more like this:

```
WHERE
    [ID] NOT IN (SELECT [ID] FROM dbo.Table1)
AND [Supplier] NOT IN (SELECT [Supplier] FROM dbo.Table1)
AND ...
```

But maybe you mean something more like this:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID 
                                             AND Table1.Supplier = Table2.Supplier 
                                             AND ... )
```

Comment: This doesn't have the same semantics as a tuple `NOT IN` would

Comment: Well, given the syntax he had, I'm not exactly sure what he was trying for... it wasn't clear to me at all. I just tried to translate it as best I could into a real "IN" syntax.

Comment: the syntax is already a real syntax - just not one currently supported by SQL Server. It will look across columns in the same row - the rewrite will return false if the Id exists in the other table or the supplier exists in the other table even if the rows are different.

Comment: I only work with SQL Server. I've never seen such a weird syntax before. Honestly couldn't make heads or tails of what he was trying to do. OH well.

Comment: There is no obligation to post an answer if you have to guess what they are attempting